# Started monerod on cli but it just hangs, or am I not suppose to see anything happen while downloading ?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod

Started the monerod on the terminal and it just hangs, or am I suppose to just wait and expect nothing to show up?

[image]

```
[xxx@host monero-v0.10.3.1]$ ./monerod 
2017-07-27 18:32:35.591     7fe26d4f9780        INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
2017-07-27 18:32:35.592     7fe26d4f9780        INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:282 Monero 'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.3.1-release)
2017-07-27 18:32:35.592     7fe26d4f9780        INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:55        Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2017-07-27 18:32:35.592     7fe26d4f9780        INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:60        Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2017-07-27 18:32:35.592     7fe26d4f9780        INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:63     Initializing p2p server...
sendto: Operation not permitted
2017-07-27 18:32:36.027     7fe26d4f9780        INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:68     P2p server initialized OK
2017-07-27 18:32:36.027     7fe26d4f9780        INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:58     Initializing core rpc server...
2017-07-27 18:32:36.027     7fe26d4f9780        INFO    global  contrib/epee/include/net/http_server_impl_base.h:70     Binding on 127.0.0.1:18081
2017-07-27 18:32:36.027     7fe26d4f9780        INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:63     Core rpc server initialized OK on port: 18081
2017-07-27 18:32:36.028     7fe26d4f9780        INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:73    Initializing core...
2017-07-27 18:32:36.028     7fe26d4f9780        INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:326     Loading blockchain from folder /home/nxt/.bitmonero/lmdb ...
2017-07-27 18:32:36.030     7fe26d4f9780        WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb      src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:71   Error attempting to retrieve a hard fork version at height 0 from the db: MDB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found
2017-07-27 18:32:37.605     7fe26d4f9780        INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:78    Core initialized OK
2017-07-27 18:32:37.605     7fe26d4f9780        INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:68     Starting core rpc server...
2017-07-27 18:32:37.605 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:73     Core rpc server started ok
2017-07-27 18:32:37.606 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:78     Starting p2p net loop...
2017-07-27 18:32:38.608 [P2P1]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1098
**********************************************************************
The daemon will start synchronizing with the network. It may take up to several hours.

You can set the level of process detailization* through "set_log <level|categories>" command*,
where <level> is between 0 (no details) and 4 (very verbose), or custom category based levels (eg, *:WARNING)

Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands.
**********************************************************************

^C2017-07-27 18:33:22.869       [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:80     p2p net loop stopped
2017-07-27 18:33:22.932 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:78     Stopping core rpc server...
2017-07-27 18:33:22.933 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global  src/daemon/daemon.cpp:145       Node stopped.
2017-07-27 18:33:22.933 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:90     Deinitializing rpc server...
2017-07-27 18:33:22.933 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:90     Deinitializing p2p...
2017-07-27 18:33:22.934 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:89    Deinitializing core...
2017-07-27 18:33:22.938 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:77        Stopping cryptonote protocol...
2017-07-27 18:33:22.938 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:81        Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
```

Comment: Please provide more information on your system (which OS, whether home device or VPS, amount of RAM, etc).  That `sendto: Operation not permitted` is strange.

Comment: It's probably timing out on some DNS call. Wait a few minutes to see if that's the case. If so, it should continue just fine.